# Binding ListBox to a table

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 application.

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID | Name | Description
```

I want to show in a ListBox all **names** in table. And I want to identify when a user select a row and get its ID.

How can I store **ID** inside ListBoxItem? And how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a data object associated with each row (we'll call it `MyDataRow` for now), set the **ItemsSource** property of your ListBox to the collection of your `MyDataRow` instances. Then, in your ListBox, set the **DisplayMemberPath** to **Name**. This will make the ListBox bind to your actual data objects but actual display the value of the **Name** property.

When you handle the **SelectionChanged** event the value of the **SelectedItem** property will be an instance of your `MyDataRow` class, so you can get the ID using code like this:

`var id = ((MyDataRow)_myListBox.SelectedItem).ID;`

Comment: And.. where can I learn to do that? I only have a datasource made with a XML file.

Comment: This should help: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/data-binding-the-wp7-listpicker-to-xml-data-using-expressionblend-4

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But I have another question. On that table I have another column to indicate language (en, es, ...) How can I set a where clause to ItemsSource? Or can I do a view?

Comment: ok, I've found this: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-xml-reading-filtering-and-databinding

Answer (score 1):

Use binding is the best way. See my code below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="List1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=List1,Path=SelectedItem.ID}" />
```

// CSharp Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Collection<Entity> source = new Collection<Entity> { 
            new Entity{ID = "1", Name = "Name1", Description = "This is Name1"},
            new Entity{ID = "2", Name = "Name2", Description = "This is Name2"},
            new Entity{ID = "3", Name = "Name3", Description = "This is Name3"},
        };

        List1.ItemsSource = source;
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```